# Storing JSON: Javascript vs HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm get a json object from an Ajax request like this:

```
"items":[      
  {  
      "id":923,
      "id_str":"608475747557236737",
      "uid":407388514,
      "date":"Wed Jun 10 03:28:17 +0000 2015",
      "status":0,
  },
  {  
     "id":923,
      "id_str":"608475747557236737",
      "uid":407388514,
      "date":"Wed Jun 10 03:28:17 +0000 2015",
      "status":0,
   }
]
```

I loop the json object and generate HTML elements.

My question is if Is best store the json information in each HTML element such us: `data-prop1=""`, `data-prop2=""` etc, o i keep the data in a javascript var like array?

The information of the HTML element will be send via Ajax request to the server again, so i want to store and restore to send.

Comment: Why not to store it as object in javascript?

Comment: Which format will you send data again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a performance point of view it is far better to store it in a variable instead of directly on your HTML elements

- DOM operations are *expensive* (selecting/accessing that HTML element
  which holds the data).
- It's also the most cross-browser compatible way
  since `data attributes` only apply on HTML5 browsers

It also easier to `console.log` it, and inspect it in your Developer tools.

Personally, I use the `data-*` attributes only when little information (such as a couple of attributes) is needed to be stored for each element and that information would be send by a *direct click/hover event on the element itself* - Otherwise it doesn't make much sense to me to store it within the DOM.

None is stopping you from saving whole JSON's on the DOM, if you find it easier - However if you keep on doing it you will end up with a very convoluted markup and a pattern that just looks terrible

Answer (score 1):

I am working with a similar scenario currently and I've chosen to implement a model on the client's side which holds the information, because storing everything in the DOM could be harmful to the overall performance.

In other words I have some HTML code, for example

```
<div id='element-1' class='element'>foo</div>
<div id='element-2' class='element'>bar</div>
<div id='element-3' class='element'>baz</div>
```

which corresponds to the recieved data

```
[{id:1, text:'foo'}, {id:2, text:'bar'}, {id:3, text:'baz'}]
```

and instead of using DOM I have a model object which holds the data, is accessible from everywhere and has methods to search in the data, render it and so on.

A very simplified example of such object could look like this:

```
function Model() {

    this.data = []; //after recieving the data via Ajax it is stored here

    this.find = find;
    function find(id) {
        //cycle through data and return the correct record
    }

    this.render = render;
    function render(id) {
        var obj = find(id);

        // find the element with $('#element-'+id) and update it's text
    }

    this.update = update;
    function update(id, text) {
        var obj = find(id);
        obj.text = text;
    }        
}
```

The advantage is that you don't make the DOM heavy and you keep your data in a clean and organized way and the downfall is that you have to keep your displayed data and model data in sync.

Comment: Of course remember to create an instance of the object when you initialize your project with for example `var myModel = new Model();` :)

Comment: Thanks Dropout !! it seems that what you're doing is very similar to mine. Is there any way to avoid the loop through all items to find specific id? Maybe I can have about 100+ items in the array, will be efficient? I'm thinking in the possibility to create an array with custom index, for eg Model.data[item_id] = {json object}.

Comment: Sorry, I'm only using a very simple tree structure for the data and the performance isn't an issue on my side. Maybe you could use some sort of a folder-like system in which IDs would indicate in which branch the data is stored, but this is just an idea. I'm afraid I can't help you with that.

Comment: Droput! I found a solution:

1) The Model
    var Model = { data: {} }

2) Storing data with custom ID
Model.data[ the_item.id ] = item_json_object;

3) Geting back the data from ID
data = Model.data[ target_id ];

Comment: @mauriblint yeah sure, you can have the Model as an array of data.. Choose what better suits you.. I've chosen a bit more complex model because I need a lot of functions attached to it.. Thanks for the info though :)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend not to store anywhere in html, as you going to pass elements to another ajax request. So just create variable in javascript and store it temporary.